# Can I cite a comment by a reviewer of a conference paper?

Tags: citations, peer-review

While researching for my thesis, I found a source containing comments by the reviewers for a particular conference on the acceptance of papers. 
see https://openreview.net/forum?id=HkAClQgA-

If I am to cite one of the ***comments by a reviewer***, how can I do that? 
Or rather can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! It would be useful to add the purpose of the citation, because, strictly speaking, you can even cite what's written on a piece of toilet paper, _if you need to_  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you cite this? Yes. Should you cite this? Probably No.

This source is a normal website which can be cited. How exactly you can do this depends on your citation style and type of document you are writing. Most likely, you must give the URL and also have to include the day when you accessed this website. You also may have to save/download the cited page since it may become unavailable. If in doubt, talk to your thesis advisor.

Nevertheless, citing a review *might* be a bad idea, depending on the intention of the citation. Compared with a usual scientific paper, a single review was not peer-reviewed and may contain incorrect information. Usually, you should be able to find the same information somewhere else in a better source.
If you give more information on *what* and *why* you want to cite this, better recommendations can be given!

Comment: Hey thank you for the input! :)  This is for a literature review for my Master thesis, to be submitted for a university. I was hoping that I can base my review of a paper and add more weight to it by citing a reviewers comment as well.. But yes,  I see that this info _may_ be incorrect :S